# How do I change my applications initial screenlocation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, monogame

Whenever I start a new application in Visual Studio, it gets created in the middle of the screen. Since i have a small laptop, I have to move it every time.

Is there any way to change the initial application location on the screen?

This is a Monogame Content Project.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the properties of your form, change the StartPosition to Manual and then set the Location x,y to wherever you want the top corner of the form to be.

For the XNA Monogame project see http://projectdrake.net/blog/2013/03/31/tutorial-setting-window-position-in-xnamonogame/

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

namespace MonoGameExtensions {
    public static class GameWindowExtensions {
        public static void SetPosition(this GameWindow window, Point position) {
            OpenTK.GameWindow OTKWindow = GetForm(window);
            if (OTKWindow != null) {
                OTKWindow.X = position.X;
                OTKWindow.Y = position.Y;
            }
        }

        public static OpenTK.GameWindow GetForm(this GameWindow gameWindow) {
            Type type = typeof(OpenTKGameWindow);
            System.Reflection.FieldInfo field = type.GetField("window", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (field != null)
                return field.GetValue(gameWindow) as OpenTK.GameWindow;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i should have added, this is a monogame project. I've edited the question.

Comment: Might check out this tutorial:http://projectdrake.net/blog/2013/03/31/tutorial-setting-window-position-in-xnamonogame/

Comment: Works like a charm! Apparently my google-fu needs a bit of work. If you edit your question to include the code snippet I can accept it.